# Should the header ctgmath/ tgmath.h be used?

Tags: c++, c, header

Should I use the header ctgmath? It automatically includes cmath and ccomplex. It has some predefined macros. Should its inclusion affect my code or usage of these macros decrease the efficacy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Simply including the headers in your code doesn't decrease the efficiency... Also macro inclusion doesn't change the speed cos, macro expansion happens during compile time not at run time.

Comment: Some moments ago I could not find the macros defined in the header. But now I am unable to find them. I have searched cpluplus.com and other websites. Can you help me find them?

Comment: @Level31 According to C++11 §26.8/1, "The header <ctgmath> simply includes the headers <ccomplex> and <cmath>." I.e. it does not define any macros. Standard C++ does not support type-generic expressions and I've heard mumblings from the committee that they're incompatible, although I don't know what the difficulty is.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: For C++ the interactions with regular overloading would have to be defined. Personally I'd say that C should have adopted a subset of C++ overloading instead of inventing a new, incompatible mechanism, but that's too late now.

Comment: @MSalters What interaction? Type-generic expressions are like static `switch`es. The operand subexpressions are completely independent.

Comment: A new question is that should fmax be used to return the maximum of two integers?

Comment: @Level31 No, C++ does not have integral overloads for `fmax`. Use `std::max` instead.